# Creating a multiple choice quiz database

Tags: database, database-design

I would like to know if my database setup is sufficient for a multiple choice quiz. If there is a better way of approaching this please let me know.

- It has three types of tests(Clerical, Numerical, Verbal).
- The user    will have to answer all three tests and the score for
  each is stored
- I'm storing the choices and the correct answer in the tbl_answer so
  that I could retrieve and output in the application

tbl_user(ID, name, clerical_score, numerical_score, verbal_score)

tbl_quiz(ID, clerical, numerical, verbal)

tbl_question(ID, FK:quiz_ID, question)

tbl_answer(ID, FK:question_ID, choice_1, choice_2, choice_3, choice_4, correct_answer)

Comment: I'd try to avoid tables with confusing names like 'ID'. Consider using 'User_ID, Quiz_ID etc

Comment: That seems a decent enough schema.

Comment: @RichBenner: Interesting, because I would argue the exact opposite.  Terms like `User.User_ID` are very redundant to me.  (Though I'd also argue against prefixing every table with `tbl_`, for similar reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

according to your schema, the releation between tbl_question-tbl_answer will be One to One. So, it is better to group the two tables in one : 
**tbl_question**(ID, FK:quiz_ID, questionn , choice_1, choice_2, choice_3, choice_4, correct_answer)

Answer (score 0):

> As per your scenario I would suggest this:-
>
> user_table(user_id(primary_key),user_name,clerical_score,
>   numerical_score, verbal_score, total_score);
>
> clerical_table(c_question_id,(primary_key), c_questions, c_option1,
>   c_option2, c_option3, c_option4, marks);
>
> numerical_table(n_question_id,(primary_key), n_questions, n_option1,
>   n_option2, n_option3, n_option4, marks);
>
> verbal_table(v_question_id,(primary_key), v_questions, v_option1,
>   v_option2, v_option3, v_option4, marks);
>
> ->Now remember keep option1 always correct one in all three tables.
>   ->So when you fetch options from tables during displaying the options use "RANDOM" function to suffle the options even shuffel the questions
>   when starting new seccsion for each and every candidate.
>   ->THen to match the correct option just take the key in your web page that the candidate has selected and match it with option1 of the table
>   for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Why three fields for the quiz type in `tbl_quiz`? It expect something like `tbl_quiz(ID, quiztype_id)` instead.

- **tbl_user** (id, name)
- **tbl_quiztype** (id, description)
- **tbl_quiz** (id, fk:quiztype_id)
- **tbl_question** (id, fk:quiz_id, question, choice_1, choice_2, choice_3, choice_4, correct_answer_no)
- **tbl_user_result** (id, fk:user_id, fk:quiztype_id, points)

instead of the latter you might also store all answers rather then the aggregated results:

- **tbl_user_answer** (id, fk:user_id, fk:question_id, answer_no)

And if you want to allow for different numbers of answer choices in the future, you could replace tbl_question by

- **tbl_question** (id, fk:quiz_id, question, correct_answer_no)
- **tbl_answer** (id, fk:question_id, answer_no, answertext)